# Redirect from Controller with custom data to be passed

Tags: .net-core, controller, asp.net-core-webapi, single-page-application

I am new to .netcore and I am migrating one of my websites to the .netcore app with React.

I have an issue with redirect:

After signup, an email is sent to the user with a link to activate their account. The link calls an API. The link looks like this:
http://host:port/api/user/activate?username=<username>&activationCode=<activationcode>

All works fine, and the link activates the user. However, I want the user to be redirected to the main login page which is also in http://host:port/.

This is not the issue. I am using this code and it works.

```
[Route("Activate")]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Activate(string Username, string ActivationCode)
        {
           // whatever I need to do for activation

          
           result.UrlHelper.ActionContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("./");

            return result;
        }
```

This works. However, it is not complete. I want to show a message on the root page saying "Activation is successful". So I want to pass on some data.

I tried:

```
   result.UrlHelper.ActionContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("message", message);
   result.UrlHelper.ActionContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("success", success.ToString());
```

But no header is added.

Then, I tried querystring

```
string requeststr = $"{this.Request.Scheme}://{this.Request.Host}{this.Request.PathBase}?message={message}&success={success.ToString()}";
            result.UrlHelper.ActionContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(requeststr);
```

and this is also doesnt work as the query string is not added.

Any idea why this happens? And other alternative solution?

Answer (score 2):

You have a few possibilities. If your main login page is directly in your application you can use at the end of the method

```
return RedirectToAction("actionName", "controllerName");
```

or for sure you can use redirect to any page by this

```
return Redirect("https://google.com");
```

More info about redirect (please select .net version of your api in the dropdown):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.redirecttoaction?view=aspnetcore-7.0